# How to format html code well in PhpStorm?

Tags: html, format, phpstorm

PhpStorm is fantastic, 99% fantastic to me. Somewhere uncomfortable, such as seems no way to format html attribute value align. I set the html code style, but nothing change.

Is a way solve it out ?

[image: Wrong Html Attr Value Format]

Comment: Is it HTML file or PHP file?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, in any editor, not just PhpStorm.

You are using a custom HTML attribute, and the value inside the attribute has to be taken verbatim. Maybe in some cases you can't change the number of spaces, or new-line characters without changing the meaning of the information of the value.
Since the editor doesn't know about your specific usage of this attribute it has to leave it intact.

You can always use tabs/spaces to align your code manually.